# how to add image in flutter TextFormField inside prefixIcon

Tags: image, flutter, size, textfield, assets

in the TextFormField the prefixIcon take a widget,
I used the Image.asset(lock,width: 10,height: 10,),
but it had big size bigger than 20,
what I do?

Comment: Add some of your code you tried with `TextFormField`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the prefixIcon as follow in the TextFormField Widget,

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/facebook_logo.jpg',
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
```

> prefixIcon is a 48*48 px wide widget by default as per flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefixIcon.html). so to decrease the size of the icon add the padding on all the size and you will be able to adjust as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 prefixIcon: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0)),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            "asset url",
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
          )),
```

Comment: Check out [answer] to improve this answer.